# CKEditor Font and Size menues do not show actual style

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, font-size

I'm trying to find solution for the following problem:

If I select text in editor and change font with 'Font'-dropdown, this dropdown will show correct font when I step on edited part of the text in the editor. But if I haven't yet changed font, then 'Font'-dropdown doesn't display actual font. And there is the same problem with a 'Size' dropdown.

If it's possible, help me please at least to determine the direction in which I have to dig to resolve this annoying problem.

Thank you for your time.

before editing:
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8440/8019979666_cac44116c6_b.jpg

after editing:
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8170/8019969770_d7e1456f86_z.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as expected because there actually isn't any user-inputted definition for the font or the size at the time before editing happened. It could be basically any font and can be defined with the CSS stylesheet of the page that is viewing the content. When the text is in the editor, it is specified by the `content.css` of the editor, which by default uses the font

```
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
```

Often, however the actual output of the editor does not use the same stylesheet and so the font could be whatever the default of the browser is or what is defined in the stylesheet of the page that hosts the content from the editor.

The dropdowns specify the font that the user has selected for text - if the user has not selected anything and leaves it as the default values the box should not display anything :)

Comment: I agree with this answer, but if its matter of showing something before a text is inputed or caret set to some text then theres font default label: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_defaultLabel and same for size

Comment: Good addition! I didn't think of it that way.